# Which is the right OpenGL version

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, opengl

I am trying to run a software that needs at least an OpenGL shading language version of 1.4. It works fine with I use my laptops Nvidia card but crashes with the intel gpu. I am trying to debug why that happens. Currently I think it has something to do with the GLSL version (OpenGL shading language).
Here is the output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` when I run it using the Nvidia card:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GT 730M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.116
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.116
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 390.116
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

When I run it with the Intel iGPU  I get

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.2.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.2.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 19.2.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions
```

The difference between the two that might explain my problem is this line

```
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

while on Nvidia it is:

```
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
```

But then why is are there 3 versions of that GLSL? What do they mean?

```
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
```

Comment: First is for Nvidia, second for Intel, and third is for Embeded Opengl, aka Opengl ES.

Comment: How is the first for Nvidia when I clearly stated that I ran that on an Intel cpu. I get a similar result on Intel only laptops with no nvidia whatsoever.

Comment: I quote "...when I run it using the Nvidia card...". Clear now?

Comment: I mean the 3 versions occur regardless of using intel or nvidia. OpenGL core profile, OpenGL and OpenGL ES.

Comment: Well, yes, These are hardware capabilities, reported by glxinfo, and they do not change no matter what you use and on what.